# Rails: Active Record valid? returning true for uniqueness even when its not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a column called `key` which I am testing for uniqueness by using

`validates_uniqueness_of :key, scope: :user_id`

I also need to do some processing in which I am checking if a record is `valid?`, but it is incorrectly returning `true` even when `key` is present.

for example, my table already has a row where key = `1585563947.csv` and user_id = `1`

Now, during processing, when I am checking again something like this

```
myModelObject = Model.new({key: 1585563947.csv, user_id: 1})
myModelObject.valid? # returns true
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Any help with suggested workaround would be really great. I need to check if a record is valid where all my model validations are checked for.

Comment: You wrote you have a row where `key = 1585563947.csv` but do you have a row where `key = 1585563947.csv` and `user_id = 1`?

Comment: @MarekLipka, my bad, thanks for pointing out. I have updated the question

Comment: attach your `Model` code where validations applied. Or write some test with rspec to cover this validation

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev, i have already added the model code above, do you need the controller code?

Comment: it is not related with controller. Have you written test which covers this validation?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev, actually have nit written tests